# QML/WebGL - How to stop DefaultFileDialog from returning unusable paths on Windows?

Tags: qt, dialog, qml, webgl

**Problem description**

When building a QML application on Windows for the desktop that contains a FileDialog, the default Windows file dialog is shown. This one works as expected, returning a path to the selected file or folder that has a prefix (file:///) before the path. Only once WebGL comes into play, the problem appears.

Building for the WebGL platform and connecting via browser will default the file dialog to DefaultFileDialog, which behaves drastically different upon selection of (sub-)directories. Lets say we start out with this path in the dialog (clipped to focus on the ROI):

[image: First folder path in dialog, starts with C:/]

After selecting a subdirectory (single click):

[image: After selecting one of the subdirectories, the C:/ is replaced with c:/. Note that this will not happen if a shortcut is selected (resets to C:/)]

Another click enters that directory and replaces the path with:

[image: Entering the selected subdirectory removes the colon and pushes two additional slashs to the front (//c/)]

If another selection is taken in the subdirectory, we finally lose the drive letter:

[image: No more drive letter available. This pathstyle should work on Linux, I think, but does not work on Windows anymore]

The path is something that I expect to work on Linux which might be the reason why I could not find any additional information on this behavior. Additional steps into subdirectories do not break the path further:

[image: Additional steps into subdirectories do not break the path further]

**My search so far**

I have google'd it, searched Stack Overflow and tried to regex my way through this problem, but so far, no luck.

**Question**

Is there a way to stop DefaultFileDialog instances from *optimizing* my path selections into uselessness on Windows? Ideally, I'd like to keep the system file dialog when not running the application for WebGL, but this is no hard requirement for me.

*EDIT: @mike510a revealed other requirements that I missed:*

1. *The drive letter may be any valid one, as within the dialog, the drive can be changed. Therefore hardcoding a drive letter to replace the one lost within the dialog does not work.*
2. *Due to the unknown number of steps taken before accepting a file or folder, it cannot be assumed that the drive letter was already cut from the returned QString.*

**Sample code**

Modify a project created by QtCreator (4.13.2 in my case, empty QtQuick project).

```qml
# autogenerated
QT += quick

CONFIG += c++11

# You can make your code fail to compile if it uses deprecated APIs.
# In order to do so, uncomment the following line.
#DEFINES += QT_DISABLE_DEPRECATED_BEFORE=0x060000    # disables all the APIs deprecated before Qt 6.0.0

SOURCES += \
        main.cpp

RESOURCES += qml.qrc

# Additional import path used to resolve QML modules in Qt Creator's code model
QML_IMPORT_PATH =

# Additional import path used to resolve QML modules just for Qt Quick Designer
QML_DESIGNER_IMPORT_PATH =

# Default rules for deployment.
qnx: target.path = /tmp/$${TARGET}/bin
else: unix:!android: target.path = /opt/$${TARGET}/bin
!isEmpty(target.path): INSTALLS += target
```

```cpp
#include <QGuiApplication>
#include <QQmlApplicationEngine>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
  QCoreApplication::setAttribute(Qt::AA_EnableHighDpiScaling);

  QGuiApplication app(argc, argv);

  app.setOrganizationName("Something");        // modified to avoid QML warning
  app.setOrganizationDomain("Something.else"); // modified to avoid QML warning

  QQmlApplicationEngine engine;
  const QUrl url(QStringLiteral("qrc:/main.qml"));
  QObject::connect(&engine, &QQmlApplicationEngine::objectCreated,
                   &app, [url](QObject *obj, const QUrl &objUrl) {
    if (!obj && url == objUrl)
      QCoreApplication::exit(-1);
  }, Qt::QueuedConnection);
  engine.load(url);

  return app.exec();
}
```

```qml
import QtQuick 2.15
import QtQuick.Window 2.15
import QtQuick.Dialogs 1.2
import QtQuick.Controls 2.5
import QtQuick.Layouts 1.3

Window {
    width: 640
    height: 480
    minimumHeight: 320
    minimumWidth: 480
    visible: true
    title: qsTr("Hello World")
    color: "grey"

    RowLayout {
        anchors.fill: parent

        Label {
            text: "File path:"
            Layout.column: 0
        }
        TextEdit {
            id: pathTextEdit
            readOnly: true
            clip: true
            Layout.column: 1
            Layout.fillWidth: true
            Rectangle {
                z: -1
                anchors.fill: parent
                radius: 3
                color: "white"
            }
        }
        Button {
            text: "Select file"
            Layout.column: 2
            onClicked: {
                pathSelection.visible = true
            }
        }
    }

    FileDialog {
        id: pathSelection
        visible: false
        width: 300
        height: 300
        selectFolder: true
        onAccepted: {
            pathTextEdit.text = folder
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I believe you can find DefaultFileDialog.qml in the qtdeclarative source tree, you could just copy that into your project folder and modify it by removing whatever code is causing the undesired behavior too.

Comment: This is an approach I'm trying to take after talking to the Qt Support. Fingers crossed that I get the solution they provided to work :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With the help of Qt Support, a solution could be found. The issue responsible for the behavior is found in DefaultFileDialog.qml, more specifically, the function `dirDown`. It is fixable by replacing

```diff
root.folder = "file://" + path
```

with

```diff
root.folder = root.pathToUrl(path)
```

and rebuilding Qt afterwards. The entire patch reads like this:

```diff
--- a/src/dialogs/DefaultFileDialog.qml
+++ b/src/dialogs/DefaultFileDialog.qml
@@ -115,7 +115,7 @@ AbstractFileDialog {
 
     function dirDown(path) {
         view.selection.clear()
-        root.folder = "file://" + path
+        root.folder = root.pathToUrl(path)
     }
     function dirUp() {
         view.selection.clear()
```

This patch was submitted for inclusion with Qt 5.15.3.

Answer (score 0):

I'm pretty sure that because the WebGL platform uses a different schema than the Windows filesystem directory structure, you will get weird folders. You can use the schema `file://` to translate URLS into pointers to files on the local machine, You can use the `folder` property along with file:///C:/Users/whatever   or do the following...

To grab the operating System's underlying filesystem's locations, you can use the `folder` property with the value  `shortcuts.home`  as stated here: https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtquick-dialogs-filedialog.html

```
 FileDialog {
        id: pathSelection
        visible: false
        width: 300
        height: 300
        selectFolder: true

        // point to an operating system location and you should get
        // a usable URL

        folder: shortcuts.home

        onAccepted: {
            pathTextEdit.text = folder
        }
    }
```

Comment: Thank you for providing this answer. Sadly, it does not help me in this case as the initial location is fine, but once I am in the dialog, the returned value saved in `folder` is unusable (as the drive letter gets dropped when run for the WebGL due to the DefaultFileDialog being used instead of the System file dialog, I assume). So I start in a valid path but lose that while working myself throught the subdirectories, as shown in the screenshots-

Comment: Couldn't you just do a fancy concantenation or something with the returned filename?  like  `QString newfile = QString("C:/%1").arg(oldfile);`   then  do  `newfile.replace("/", QDir::Separator());`  to switch the slashes??

Comment: This would be the solution if I could guarantee two things:

1. I am always working on the C drive
2. The drive letter is always dropped.

I'll edit the question to explicitly state the drive letter requirement. Thank you!